# I want to make an external script accessible to all the routes in an angular project

Tags: javascript, angular

I have already added the script to index.html but can't access it inside code of any component of my angular Project.
It is however accessible from the index.html.

The Script: `<script src="https://extension-files.twitch.tv/helper/v1/twitch-ext.min.js"></script>`

I want this to be accessible in all of my routes of my Angular project.

Comment: It's been long I coded with angular but I suppose there is a global script file just as there is a global css file. Someone should correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: If the script os css has been added in index file then it might be applicable to entire component. So can you recheck.

Comment: They call it a single page application because the html of your routes are dynamically inserted into index.html via the `<app-root>` tag. Inspect any page of your application and you will see the script there. Could you please edit your question to explain what you are attempting to do with the script and what exactly is not working?

Comment: @ChrisHamilton I have this script added to my index.html and is accessible there, but it is **not accessible in any of the routes** I have created (On code), while I can still access it on the browser console for these routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is available globally, just needed the right way to access the Methods.

Add

```
declare let Twitch: any;
```

at the top of with the imports in the ts file and then the methods can be accessed with

```
Twitch.ext
```